# Disable fancybox on handhelds

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, fancybox, handheld

I need to make sure that upon clicking a link to view a html file, on an iPhone or Android or any handheld, it doesn't use Fancybox to view it, as it does on a computer.

I've tried ways with @media with no luck.

Is there any code to disable certain bits of javascript depending on what device it is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Andre's solution will work for a specific subset of devices, but a better approach might be to do it based on screen size, since that's presumably why you don't want to use facnybox (because the screen is too small).

How about this:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 500 && window.innerHeight < 500) {

    //small screen device - don't use fancy box
}
```

You can swap out the width and height for whatever the threshold is for fancybox looking okay.

Comment: i like your approach, but the numbers are wrong. IPhonem for instance, has a resolution of 960*640

Comment: Yes, but the iPhone uses virtual pixels, so it reports it's window size as 320x480 so as not to break apps and sites built for older iPhones. Try it if you don't believe me!

Comment: There are some giant Android phones that may have more than 500pixels resolution, but if the screen is that big then presumably it's okay to use fancy box anyway - that's the point of this approach - you are testing the device beaded on it's actual capabilities, not an arbitrary category like "handheld" which might also include laptop-sized devices like the iPad.

Comment: Android devices measure their screen sizes in DIPs (device independent pixels) which are like the virtual pixels used by the iPhone, so I think the same would apply. I'm an iOS developer not an Android dev though, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll give those a try. The main reason I don't want fancybox on the phones/tablets is because you can't scroll the iframe on most of them. Also it doesn't center nicely in the window.

Comment: Does this work when the window is resized, for example from big to small?

Comment: It's based on window size, so it cannot distinguish between a small window on a large screen and a small screen. For that you need another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this approach and it is working fine for me...

```
if( $(window).width() > 480 && (!navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
!navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/))
){
  $(".royalSlide").click().fancybox({
     'overlayShow'  : false,
     'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
     'transitionOut'    : 'elastic'
  });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For fancybox 2 this worked for me.

```js
$(".fancybox-img").click( function( e ) {
    if ( window.innerWidth < 799 ) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
$(".fancybox-img").fancybox( {
    margin     : 100,
    autoSize   : true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
 navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/)
 ){
 // your fancybox instantiation here
}
```

but it will never be 100% accurate

Comment: You can do that with a single regex expression: navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|WebOS|iPhone|iPod|Blackberry/i) -it's a bit cleaner. As you say though, it's not ideal because Android might be a tablet, or the device may pretend to be Internet Explorer for compatibility, or it may be some Chinese mobile device you've never heard of, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking inside of the box, no pun intended, a non-js solution:

```
.fancybox-overlay {
    display: none !important;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .fancybox-overlay {
        display: block !important;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

disable fancybox with screen size

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
.fancybox-is-open {
    display: none !important;
}};
```